# Circular References in RavenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb, circular-reference

I'm using RavenDB with models like:

```
public class Cart {
    List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}

public class Item {
    public Cart Cart;
}
```

When I add an `Item` to a `Cart`, I wire up both sides of the relationship.

**How does RavenDB handle serializing & deserializing this?**  Will the reference to `Cart` be assigned automatically or is there a way to manually wire it on load?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you save cart you will get an exception 'Self referencing loop detected...' when you call `SaveChanges()`.

The fix is easy. You add the `[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` attribute to Cart. This tells the serializer to store Item's Cart as a reference instead of as a new object.

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)] 
public class Cart
{
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}

public class Item
{
    public Cart Cart;
}
```

I also wanted to mention that it IS property deserialized. In other words, Cart is re-assigned to Item when it is loaded.

```
var cart = new Cart();
cart.Items.Add(new Item { Cart = cart });
session.Store(cart);
session.SaveChanges();

...

var cart = session.Query<Cart>().First();
Assert.ReferenceEquals(cart, cart.Items.First().Cart); //this works
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read this to get a handle on how RavenDB works in those scenarios:
http://ravendb.net/docs/theory/document-structure-design

In this case, Item & Card would actually be serialized into the SAME document, which is likely not what you want.
References in RavenDB should include *just* the id of the references document, not the document itself.